# How get firebase value in react-native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read the value of the firebase and save it in this.state when the constructor happens. What should I do?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    return firebase.database().ref("/users" + userId)
    .once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
      var uid = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().uid)
      var nickname = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().nickname)
    }),
    this.state = {
      //uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
      uid: "",
      nickname: "",

    };
  }
```

Comment: If a user has a UID of 12345, you are referencing the path /users12345. Are you sure you're not looking for a document called 12345 in the path /users?

Answer (score 0):

The call to `setState` needs to be inside the callback:

```
firebase.database().ref("/users" + userId)
    .once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
      var uid = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().uid)
      var nickname = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().nickname)

      this.setState({
        uid: uid,
        nickname: nickname,    
      });
    }),
```